# Talend Big Data Streaming not supporting subjob

Tags: talend

I am trying to read messages from a kafka topic loading it into a tcacheoutput. then using tcacheinput in a subjob am reading conerting the data into a format, joining with another table and loading it into sql server. The problem is Big Data streaming is not allowing me to run it. it says,
java.lang.Exception: In Talend, Spark Streaming jobs only support one job. Please deactivate the extra jobs.
Is there an another way achive it? My job looks like this:

[image]

Comment: perhaps you just need "on component OK" trigger between tcacheOutput and tcacheInput ? i am not familiar with talend big data.

Comment: @Corentin onComponent ok doesnt work with tcache